# how to process files in a directory with bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Imagine that I have the directory as below:

```
dir
 |
 |--- sub1
 |     |
 |     |------filea.jpg
 |     |------fileb.jpg
 |
 |
 |--- sub2
       |
       |------filec.jpg
       |------filed.jpg
       |------sub21
                |
                |-------filee.jpg
```

What I need to do is to pass all of files which are located in the same directory as one parameter to some executable file.

For example, for the case above, I need to:

```
upload.sh dir/sub1/filea.jpg dir/sub1/fileb.jpg
upload.sh dir/sub2/filec.jpg dir/sub2/filed.jpg
upload.sh dir/sub2/sub21/filee.jpg
```

I'm not good at linux shell, what I have done is to list all of them with the script:

```
find dir -type f | while read myfile; do
    echo $myfile
done;
```

How to make a script for my need?

Comment: Do the filenames have a pattern that distinguishes them from subdirectories?

Comment: @Barmar  Yes. All of filenames have an extension. For example, filea.jpg, fileb.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/608639), [Bash script to execute command on all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10523415/608639), [How to do something to every file in a directory using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1310422/608639), [for loop over specific files in a directory using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14823830/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` to find the directories, then execute your command for all the files in the directory. Use the known extension in the wildcard to prevent it from including subdirectories.

```
shopt -s nullglob
find dir -type d | while read dir; do
    files=("$dir"/*.jpg)
    if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]
    then upload.sh "${files[@]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It doesn't work for sub21. Meaning that it works only for the first level subdirectories.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `upload.sh` doesn't work for subdirectories.

Comment: It doesn't work if I remove the whole sub1 and sub2/filec and sub2/filed, meaning that there is only `dir/sub2/sub21/filee.jpg` I changed upload.sh as echo and I got the result including dir/*.jpg, I think this line should be removed.

Comment: That will get an error because it doesn't find any matching files. But it should still go on to process the other directories. Are you using `set -e` to abort the script on errors?

Comment: When I use `echo`, I do see the result `dir/*.jpg  dir/sub2/sub21/filee.jpg`. However, I think `upload.sh` can't accept `dir/*.jpg` so we must remove it. I can't change `upload.sh` because it is a binary coming from the Internet.

Comment: What does `upload.sh` do if it's given no arguments? You can use `set -o nullglob` so that a non-matching wildcard expands to nothing instead of staying as the wildcard.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91368/checking-from-shell-script-if-a-directory-contains-files for how to test if a directory contains any files that match the wildcard. You can put an `if` statement inside the loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer to test if the directory contains any files.